# Check if Attribute('id') Exists in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if an attribute Id exists in jQuery?

I searched around and found that this should work:

```
if ($(this).attr('id').attr('id'))
{

}
```

I still get this error: TypeError: Object gauge1 has no method 'attr'

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Just... test it. If it's an empty string, then there you go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This itself will work:

```
if($(this).attr("id"))
```

Check existing jsfiddle on the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/wVqvr/4/

Comment: tried this but I get TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasAttr'

Comment: This worked, but the code the bombs on the next line. It might be easier if I add a new question.

Comment: `if (!! $(this).attr('id')) { alert(' !! rocks! '); }` .This is !! double not operator from JS.

Answer (score 9):

Just try it the old way

```
if (this.id) { 
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`is` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
if ($(this).is('[id]')) {

}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer that deals with `<div id=""></div>` situation.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($(this).attr('id')){
alert(id);
}`

Answer (score 0):

you could also just use the plain js object

```
if( this.id !== undefined && this.id.length > 0 ){
 //todo: use id
}
```

Comment: @destroy - yes, it is early. `this` is already a plain js object. I will edit the change.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="hey"></div>
<div class="you" id="woah"></div>
<div id="results"></div>​
```

jQuery:

```
var id = $('div.hey').attr('id');
if (id) {
    // Have an id.
} else {
    // Don't have an id.
}
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEVYT/